# Bounding the value of a polynomial map by the distance from the variety

Tags: complex-geometry, polynomials

Let $f_1,\ldots,f_r\in\Bbb C[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ define a map $f\colon\Bbb C^n\to\Bbb C^r$. Let $Z:=Z(f_1,\ldots,f_r)\subseteq \Bbb C^n$ be the variety cut out by the $f_i$, and assume that $Z$ is nonempty. Define 
\begin{align*}
d:\Bbb C^n &\longrightarrow \Bbb R_+ \\
x &\longmapsto \operatorname{dist}(x,Z)=\inf_{z\in Z}\|x-z\|,
\end{align*}
the distance from $Z$. I conjecture that 
$$\exists g\in\Bbb C[T]: \forall x\in\Bbb C^n: \|f(x)\|\ge |g(d(x))|.$$

**My question is:** Am I right? If so, can you name a reference or a result from which this follows?

---

For $n=r=1$, the statement is certainly true. Let $f\in\Bbb C[x]$ and write 
$$f = u\cdot (x-\lambda_1)\cdots(x-\lambda_k)$$
for $u\in\Bbb C^\times$ and $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_k\in\Bbb C$. Now, we have $Z=\{\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_k\}$ and $d(x)=\min_i |x-\lambda_i|.$ If we pick $g(T):=|u|\cdot T^k$, then 
$$|f(x)|\ge |u|\cdot|x-\lambda_1|\cdots|x-\lambda_k|\ge |u|\cdot d(x)^k = |g(d(x))|.$$

Comment: Lojasiewicz inequality?

Comment: For compact subsets of $\mathbb{C}^n$ this follows from the  classical Łojasiewicz inequality (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%81ojasiewicz_inequality). From this it shouldn't be hard to get the general result.

Comment: @MargaretFriedland: Thanks for the comment, I did not know the Lojasiewicz inequality and it reminds me strongly of my problem. However, it only works on a compact subset, and allows the function to be analytic. The former I am not willing to do, and the latter I think is too general - I think this will depend on $f$ being polynomial. For example, I think my claim is untrue for $f(x)=(x^2-1) e^x$. Consider the sequence $-k$ for $k\in\Bbb N$, it gets very far from the zero locus and still the absolute value of $f(-k)$ dwindles.

Comment: @DouglasLind: This is good news - if you find the time, could you give some more hints on how to deduce my conjectured statement from the Łojasiewicz inequality? I am afraid I don't really know how to do it.

Comment: Brownawell http://www.ams.org/journals/jams/1988-01-02/S0894-0347-1988-0928261-3/home.html and Ji, Kollar and Shiffman http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1992-329-02/S0002-9947-1992-1046016-6/S0002-9947-1992-1046016-6.pdf prove bounds of the form $|f| \geq \left( \min(|d|,1)/ (1+|z|^2) \right)^C$. For $z$ large, that isn't as good as you are asking for, so I imagine there are examples showing that you can't get what you request.

Comment: There is a stupid issue: $Z$ can be empty! Consider $(x,y) \mapsto (x,xy-1)$. In this case, presumably you would set $d=\infty$, and your result does not hold.

Comment: Or, for that matter, $x \mapsto (x,x+1)$.

Comment: Another problem: $(x,y) \mapsto xy$. Then  $d=\min(|x|, |y|)$, and of course we cannot bound $|xy|$ by a polynomial in $\min(|x|, |y|)$. After seeing all these examples, if you insist on a bound of the form $|f| \geq g(|d|)$, the only case I could imagine it working is if $r=n$ and the map $f$ is finite (equivalently, proper).

Comment: @DavidSpeyer: I am willing to assume that $Z$ is nonempty, see my edit. Still, there is the other issue you raised.

Comment: Never mind, my last comment is confused. With $d=\min(|x|,|y|)$, we have $|xy| \geq d^2$. But I still think I can make a counter-example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a counter-example. Take
$$f(x,y) = (x(1-x),xy-1)$$
So $Z = \{ (1,1) \}$. Consider now consider the family $(1/R,R)$ as $R \to \infty$. The distance from $(1/R,R)$ to $(1,1)$ goes to $\infty$, but $|f(1/R,R)| = |(1/R-1/R^2,0)|$ goes to $0$. So, if we were to have a bound of the form $|f(x,y)| > g(d(x,y))$, we'd have to have $\lim_{T \to \infty} g(T)=0$, so $g$ isn't polynomial.

The point, of course, is that $Z$ morally has a second point at $(0, \infty)$.

---

The variant where all $f_i$ are homogeneous of the same degree is also false. Set
$$f(w,x,y) = w^2 \qquad g(w,x,y) = x^2-wy.$$
As a set, $Z$ is the line $w=x=0$, so the distance from $(w,x,y)$ to $Z$ is $\sqrt{|w|^2+|x|^2}$. Now let $N$ be any positive integer and let $(w,x,y) = (r^{1+N},r,r^{1-N})$ as $r \to 0$. Then $d = \sqrt{r^2+r^{2N+2}} \sim r$, but $(f,g) = (r^{2N+2},0)$ so $|(f,g)| = r^{2N+2}$. We see that $|(f,g)|$ drops off faster than $d^{2N+2}$ and, since $N$ was arbitrary, there is no polynomial bound.

Comment: First of all, thanks. Great counterexample. Do you think it holds if the polynomials are all homogeneous of the same degree? I am asking because of your remark, and because I am willing to assume such.